# passing an array of arrow functions

Tags: arrays, typescript, arrow-functions

I need to have an array of arrow functions like so

```
//how can we contain the list of tasks?
private _tasks : ((x: T) => boolean)[];

constructor(...tasks : ((x: T) => boolean)[]) {
    this._tasks = tasks;
}
```

is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

You have your brackets wrong for inline declarations. Use `{` not `(`:

```
class Foo<T>{
    private _tasks: { ( x: T ): boolean }[];

    constructor( ...tasks: { ( x: T ): boolean }[] ) {
        this._tasks = tasks;
    }
}
```

And as steve fenton said I'd use an interface just to remove duplication.

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work for me

```
private _tasks :Array<(x: T) => boolean>;
```

Comment: In TypeScript 1.4 you'll be able to use that parenthesized syntax, or to create a type alias for that. But till that, your option is the only possible way, yes. Or you may create an interface with only one call signature, and it will be structurally identical to your signature.

Comment: I will add that `T[]` is defined to be the same as `Array<T>` so there is no loss of precision here; in most cases this is the most readable workaround (I personally hate one-overload type literals!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interface to make the type more readable:

```
interface Task<T> {
    (x: T) : boolean;
}

function example<T>(...tasks: Task<T>[]) {

}

example(
    (str: string) => true,
    (str: string) => false  
);
```